# Alternative proof of Abel's Theorem for Uniform convergence of series of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

The following is the Abel's Theorem. I proved it my own way.

> Let $g_n(x)$ be a sequence of real-valued functions such that $g_{n+1}(x)\leq g_{n}(x),\forall \,x\in T$ and $n\in\Bbb{N}.$ If $\{g_{n}\}$ is uniformly bounded on $T$, and if $\sum f_n(x)$ converges uniformly, then $\sum f_n(x)g_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $T.$

**MY TRIAL**

Let \begin{align}F_n(x)=\sum^{n}_{i=1} f_n(x),\forall \,x\in T,\;n\in\Bbb{N}\end{align}
Let $N>M,$ then 
\begin{align}
\left|S_N(x)-S_M(x) \right|
&=\left|\sum^{N}_{n=1} f_n(x)g_n(x)-\sum^{M}_{n=1} f_n(x)g_n(x)\right|\\&=\left|\sum^{N}_{n=M+1} f_n(x)g_n(x)\right|\\&=\left|\sum^{N}_{n=M+1} \left[F_n(x)-F_{n-1}(x)\right]g_n(x)\right|\\&=\left|\sum^{N}_{n=M+1}F_n(x)g_n(x)-\sum^{N}_{n=M+1}F_{n-1}(x)g_n(x)\right|\\&=\left|
\left[F_{M+1}(x)-F_{M}(x)\right]g_{M+1}(x)+\sum^{N}_{n=M+2}\left[F_n(x)-F_{n-1}(x)\right]g_n(x)\right|\\&\leq
\left|F_{M+1}(x)-F_{M}(x)\right| \left| g_{M+1}(x)\right|+\sum^{N}_{n=M+2}\left|F_n(x)-F_{n-1}(x)\right|\left|g_n(x)\right|\end{align}
Since $g_n$ is uniformly bounded, there exists $M>0$ such that 
\begin{align} \left|g_n(x)\right|\leq M_{1},\forall \,x\in T\end{align}
Also, by uniform convergence of $\sum f_n(x)$, the sequence of partial sums is uniformly Cauchy. Let $\epsilon>0.$ Then, there exists $N_1=N(\epsilon)$ such that $\forall\,N>M\geq N_1,\;\forall\,x\in T$
\begin{align} \left|F_{N}(x)-F_{M}(x)\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{M_{1}+1}\end{align}
Hence, $\forall\,N>M\geq N_1,\;\forall\,x\in T$
\begin{align}
\left|S_N(x)-S_M(x) \right|& \leq
\left|F_{M+1}(x)-F_{M}(x)\right| M_{1}+M_{1}\sum^{N}_{n=M+2}\left|F_n(x)-F_{n-1}(x)\right|\\&< \frac{M_{1}\epsilon}{M_{1}+1}+\frac{M_{1}\epsilon}{M_{1}+1}<\epsilon\end{align}
And we are done!

Please, can you help check if my proof is correct? Constructive criticisms are welcome! Thanks!

Comment: You are missing a hypothesis for $f_n$ or $\sum f_n$.  "Also, by uniform convergence of $\sum f_n(x) g_n(x)$ ..."  -- this is circular -- you are using what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @RRL: Sorry, it was a typo! I'll correct it!

Comment: This is generally called "Abel's Test" or "Abel's Test for Uniform Convergence" in the literature. And Abel's Theorem is the one about Power Series

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To resolve some confusion, here is a concise proof of Abel's test for uniform convergence.  The trick is to apply summation by parts with $f_n(x) = R_n(x) - R_{n+1}(x)$ where $R_n(x) = \sum_{j=n}^\infty f_j(x)$, rather than use partial sums $\sum_{j=1}^n f_j(x)$.

Summing by parts, we get

$$\sum_{j=n}^m f_j(x) g_j(x) = \sum_{j=n}^m (R_j(x)- R_{j+1}(x)) g_j(x) \\ = R_n(x) g_n(x) - R_{m+1}(x) g_m(x) + \sum_{j=n}^{m-1}R_{j+1}(x) ( g_{j+1}(x) - g_j(x)) $$

Using the monotonicity of the sequence $\{g_n\}$ where $|g_{j+1}(x) - g_j(x)| = g_{j}(x) - g_{j+1}(x)$, it follows that

$$\left|\sum_{j=n}^m f_j(x) g_j(x)\right| \leqslant  |R_n(x)| |g_n(x)| + |R_{m+1}(x)| |g_j(x)| + \sum_{j=n}^{m-1}|R_{j+1}(x)| ( g_{j}(x) - g_{j+1}(x))$$

By hypothesis, $\{g_n\}$ is uniformly bounded and there exists $B > 0$ such that $|g_n(x)| \leqslant B$ for all $n$ and all $x \in T$. Since $\sum f_n$ is uniformly convergent there exists $n$ such that for all $j \geqslant n$ and all $x\in T$ we have $|R_j(x)| < \epsilon/(4B)$.

Thus,

$$\left|\sum_{j=n}^m f_j(x) g_j(x)\right| \leqslant  \frac{\epsilon}{4B} \cdot B + \frac{\epsilon}{4B} \cdot B +  \frac{\epsilon}{4B}\cdot \sum_{j=n}^{m-1}(g_j(x) - g_{j+1}(x)) \\ = \frac{\epsilon}{2} +  \frac{\epsilon}{4B}(g_n(x) - g_m(x))\leqslant \frac{\epsilon}{2} +  \frac{\epsilon}{4B}(|g_n(x)| + |g_m(x)|)  \leqslant \epsilon$$

This implies uniform convergence by the Cauchy criterion.

---

Original Hint:

Summing by parts with $S_n(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n f_j(x)$, we get

$$\sum_{j=m+1}^n f_j(x) g_j(x) = g_{n+1}(x) S_n(x) - g_{m+1}(x) S_m(x) + \sum_{j=m+1}^n S_j(x)(g_j(x) - g_{j+1}(x)),$$

which implies

$$\left|\sum_{j=m+1}^n f_j(x) g_j(x)\right| \leqslant |S_n(x)||g_{n+1}(x) - g_{m+1}(x)| + |g_{m+1}(x)| |S_m(x) - S_n(x)| + \sum_{j=m+1}^n |S_j(x)|(g_j(x) - g_{j+1}(x))$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have edited the statement of the theorem and the typo in the proof. Kindly re-read and tell me if it's right! I'll upvote you still!

Comment: You are using $M$ to mean two different things.

Comment: I'll change the notation for future readers and accept yours also! Thanks a lot for your help and guidance!

Comment: @Mike:  Your proof tries to shorten my argument based on summation by parts, but there is a flaw.  You claim for all $N > M > N_1$ we have $|F_N(x) - F_M(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{(M_1+1)(N-M +1)}$ for all $x$ by uniform convergence.  However, this can't hold for all $N$ unless $|F_N-F_M|= 0$ since with $M$ fixed the RHS goes to $0$ as $N$ gets large.  You really should look at my hint and follow through with the approach in the linked answer.  Basically you have the right idea -- using the uniform convergence to find bounds -- but it breaks down.

Comment: I had to edit it to take care of some things but I have an issue with your summation by part. By direct calculation, I'm getting: \begin{align} \sum_{j=m+1}^n f_j(x) g_j(x) = g_{n}(x) S_n(x) - g_{m+1}(x) S_m(x) + \sum_{j=m+1}^{n-1} S_j(x)(g_j(x) - g_{j+1}(x)),\end{align} I'm I doing anything wrong? Kindly check again!

Comment: Mine is similar to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543777/is-my-proof-of-uniform-convergence-valid-using-summation-by-parts

Comment: We can also use this approach https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433789/questions-about-rudins-summation-by-parts

Comment: ... and what you get becomes my result by adding and subtracting $g_nS_n - g_{n+1}S_n$ so that $$g_{n}(x) S_n(x) - g_{m+1}(x) S_m(x) + \sum_{j=m+1}^{n-1} S_j(x)(g_j(x) - g_{j+1}(x)) \\ = g_{n+1}(x) S_n(x) - g_{m+1}(x) S_m(x) + \sum_{j=m+1}^{n-1} S_j(x)(g_j(x) - g_{j+1}(x))  + g_n(x)S_n(x) - g_{n+1}S_n(x) \\ = g_{n+1}(x) S_n(x) - g_{m+1}(x) S_m(x) + \sum_{j=m+1}^{n} S_j(x)(g_j(x)$$. Notice the upper limit of the sum in my expression is $n$ not $n-1$.

Comment: What? You got the same thing? That's great! I have been troubled for hours now!

Comment: They are the same thing.

Comment: Thanks RRL! Let me continue with you hint. I edited mine though!

Comment: why $S_n$ is uniformly bounded? While a uniformly convergent sequence of functions may not be uniformly bounded?@RRL

Comment: @mathodfun: You are correct.  I edited.  It would be true if each $S_n$ were bounded but not in general.  Most of the interaction here was to help the OP correct some major errors in the proof and get the summation by parts straight.

Comment: @RRL thank you. In his proof, i do not understand how the last step comes $|F_{M+1}(x)−F_M(x)|M_1+M_1\sum _{n=M+2}^N |F_n(x)−F_{n−1}(x)|< \frac {M_1\epsilon}{M_1+1}+\frac {M_1\epsilon} {M_1+1}<\epsilon$.

Comment: @RRL or could you please show in details how the last step of your hint goes to the conclusion? I am trying to prove this statement, but I got stuck at the last step.

Comment: Ok. I will clear this up for you.

Comment: @mathodfun:  I added a complete and IMO the clearest proof.  Surprisingly, I was never able to find a nice proof of the test for the uniform version of Abel's test in standard analysis books.

Comment: @RRL thank you very much for your kindness.