# Interchanging integration with summation on a specific example

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation, uniform-convergence

Consider the infinite sum
$$S=\sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^{j +1}\frac{1}{2j+1} \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^{2j}}{1-x}dx$$
and the associated integral
$$L=\int_0^1 \sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{ 1-x^{2j}}{1-x} (-1)^{j +1}\frac{1}{2j+1} dx.$$
Using in $L$ the power series for the $\arctan$ function,  one can  show that
$$L= \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x -(\pi/4) x}{x(1-x)} dx,$$
and of course $S=\sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^{j +1}  \frac{H_{2j}}{2j+1}$.
Combined with some manipulations, the standard softwares yield that $S=L=\frac{\pi}{8} \log 2$.
My question: why one can interchange in the formulas for $S$ and $L$ integration with summation?
We were unable to find an integrable upper bound for the partial sums for the integrand of $L$.
Moreover   the series representing  the integrand for $L$
definitely does not
converge uniformly on $(0,1)$. Due to a lack of monotonicity in $j$ of the summands, the Leibniz rule for alternating series
cannot be applied either. So is there any other argument garantying that $\int\sum=\sum\int$?

Answer (score 5):

The series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j +1}}{2j+1}\frac{ 1-x^{2j}}{1-x} $ is uniformly convergent on $[0,1-\delta]$ for any $\delta \in (0,1)$ as a consequence of Abel's Test.

Thus,

$$\tag{*}\int_0^1 \sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j +1}}{2j+1}\frac{ 1-x^{2j}}{1-x} \, dx  \\ =\lim_{\delta \to 0+}\int_0^{1-\delta}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j +1}}{2j+1}\frac{ 1-x^{2j}}{1-x} \, dx \\= \lim_{\delta \to 0+}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j +1}}{2j+1}\int_0^{1-\delta}\frac{ 1-x^{2j}}{1-x} \, dx\\ = \lim_{\delta \to 0+}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j +1}}{2j+1}[\underbrace{(1-\delta) + \frac{(1-\delta)^2}{2} + \cdots +\frac{(1-\delta)^{2j}}{2j}}_{\hat{H}_{2j}(1-\delta)}]$$

It is not difficult to show that the sequence $\frac{\hat{H}_{2j}(1-\delta)}{2j+1}$ is decreasing and convergent to $0$. We also have

$$0 < \frac{\hat{H}_{2j}(1-\delta)}{2j+1}\leqslant \frac{H_{2j}}{2j+1},$$

where $H_{2j}$ is the $2j$-th harmonic number. This implies that the convergence of $\frac{\hat{H}_{2j}(1-\delta)}{2j+1}$ is uniform for $\delta \in [0,1)$. Since the partial sums $\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j+1}$  are uniformly bounded, it follows from the Dirichlet test that the series on the RHS of (*) is uniformly convergent for $\delta \in [0,1)$.

Consequently, we can exchange the limit and the sum in (*) to obtain

$$\int_0^1 \sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j +1}}{2j+1}\frac{ 1-x^{2j}}{1-x} \, dx =\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j +1}}{2j+1}\int_0^{1}\frac{ 1-x^{2j}}{1-x} \, dx$$

Comment: @ RRL If the sequence of partial sums is uniformly bounded on [0,1], then the dominated convergence theorem immediately yields that one can interchange sum and integral. So the "real" problem here is to verify your claim that$||S_n||\leq 1. Could you please post this, too, since, as I wrote in the post,  we were unable to do this. Thanks.

Comment: @ray: Revised answer. Also Abel's test for uniform convergence of a series $\sum f_j(x)g_j(x)$ is valid if the sequence $g_j(x)$ is uniformly bounded and monotone.  It does not have to be decreasing as is stated in some references.  See this [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2921127/148510) and note that only monotonicity is used.

Comment: Are you sure that the sequence $\hat H_{2j}(1-\delta)/(2j+1)$ is decreasing in $j$?

Comment: Let $\alpha_j = (1-\delta)^j/j$. 

$$\frac{\hat{H}_{2j}}{2j+1} > \frac{\hat{H}_{2j+2}}{2j+3}\\\iff 2j\hat{H}_{2j}+3 \hat{H}_{2j}> (2j+1)(\hat{H}_{2j}+\alpha_{2j+1}+\alpha_{2j+2})\\\iff2\hat{H}_{2j}>(2j+1)(\alpha_{2j+1}+\alpha_{2j+2})\\\iff2\hat{H}_{2j}>(1-\delta)^{2j+1}+ \frac{2j+1}{2j+2}(1-\delta)^{2j+2}$$

Comment: RHS is true for all sufficiently large index.

Comment: The very first equality $\int_0^1 h =\lim_{delta\to 0} \int_0^{1-\delta} f$ additionally needs the fact that this infinite sum $f$ is integrable (that is, that $L$ exists). This is a consequence though of the second representation of $L$ I give in the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Fubini's theorem states that, if the absolute value of the integrand/summand doesn't change the convergence properties of the expression, then you could switch symbols. In this case, Fubini's Theorem allows switching the integral and summation symbol.

Comment: The series here does not converge absolutely.